# How to add the shipping charge to specific product shopify?

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I want to add shipping charges base on product in my shopify store.

I try but I am not found anything please help me for this.

Answer (score 0):

Shopify will provide default feature to set shipping charges base on product.

For this you need to create custom shipping rate profile.

Please follow below step to add custom shipping rate profile base on product:

1. Login to shopify admin
2. Open shipping and delivery settings from Settings menu : https://prnt.sc/w8w4ai
3. Click on create new profile link : https://prnt.sc/w8w4ai
4. Add specific product and apply rate for this products.

Hope this solution is work for you.